# How do I create a sprite asset that can be used multiple times in a scene?

Tags: image, drivers, image-sequence

I am making low poly videos of people shooting guns.  I want to be able to place sprite muzzle flashes on the tips of their guns, and be able to import that as an asset.

What I have done is created an empty to act as controller/container for an *Image on Plane* of 8 frames of a cartoonish muzzle flash. This starts and ends with a transparent image.

[image: Series of Images]

There is also a point light in there to add light to the scene.

[image: Outliner and 3D Window]

Because the muzzle flash may occur on any frame, I gave the empty properties to control light intensity and frame offset.
[image: Custom Properties to Drive Muzzle Flash]

I then created a driver to make the Image Series meshes (the two planes in the scene are linked duplicates) frame equal to the FX_Start_Frame property.

[image: Driver to Control Image Sequence Frame]

When viewing the material, this appears to work, as the frame listed is equal to what I keyframed in my custom property.
[image: Keyed Frames for Sprite]

However, despite this, whenever the image cycles over, that is hits "frame 9 of the image sequence", it acts as though no image can be found.

[image: Render Image of Issue]

What am I doing wrong here, why is blender rendering as though it does not know what image to display.

Comment: First of all, I don't know why the images aren't loading although maybe there's an issue with drivers? Have you considered changing from an image sequence to a sprite sheet? As he images appear quite small you could just make a long image strip with all frames next to each other then offset the UV to change frames